# Cannot remove NDK support from Android project

Tags: android-ndk

I am unable to remove NDK support from my Android project.  I have gone through all the workspace and project settings, including CDT builder, C/C++ build paths, etc.  I have cleaned my workspace and relaunched Eclipse.  However, my project will not build as Eclipse complains about this error:

> Program "/home/eazyigz/adt-bundle-linux-x86/android-ndk-r8c/ndk-build" not found in PATH

I really don't know what to do, as I don't even have ndk-r8c downloaded, and it's an outdated version of ndk anyway! I am on Ubuntu Linux.

Anybody knows?

Comment: Probably under external builders in the project properties; might have been there if the project was moved from another machine.

Comment: Project was pushed to Git from Windows, and cloned again on Ubuntu.  So maybe, yes.

Comment: That is a common way for something like this to happen, however the path from the error message probably did not come from a working configuration on a windows system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I reinstalled Eclipse.  Then I deleted my project and re-imported it into the workspace.  Now I don't get that error anymore.  Problem solved.

Comment: For me I didn't have to go that far.  I just deleted the project (did not remove disk contents) and then imported the existing project back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C/C++ aspect to your code which references the Android NDK plugin for Eclipse, you need to have the NDK location set in the NDK plugin preferences:
[image: NDK location]